# When doing git checkout and checking the branch it shows - * (no branch)

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-checkout

After doing checkout with tag server_8_2_4 am getting this:

```
root@dhp# git branch
* (no branch)
  master
```

Is my current branch now server_8_2_4? Or what exactly happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you checkout a tag, you have a so-called "detached HEAD", which means that you are not on any branch. If you create new commits in this state, they are not on any branch. If you then switch to a branch, those commits are dangling and only preserved as long as the reflog of HEAD still points to them if you do not move those commits to a branch or create a new branch for them.

Comment: @Kautler: Great Explanation! So what you are saying is, with "detached HEAD" - i can still get make changes to my code and compile it on my local machine..in my case the branch server_8_2_4?

Comment: Yes, except that you are **NOT** on branch `server_8_2_4`. You checked out a tag and thus have a detached HEAD and are on no branch at all. If you want to create a branch `server_8_2_4` from where you are and switch to it, do `git checkout -b server_8_2_4` if you are on master and want to create a new branch `server_8_2_4` from tag `server_8_2_4` and switch to it do `git checkout -b server_8_2_4 server_8_2_4`. Or if you just want to create the branch but not switch to it, just do `git branch server_8_2_4 server_8_2_4` from anywhere or `git branch server_8_2_4` if you have the tag checked out.